# Why isn't the Isdigit function working properly?

Tags: c

I wrote this short code to test my understanding of the `isdigit` function:

```
int inChar;
printf("enter input:");
scanf(" %d", &inChar);

if (isdigit(inChar))
   printf("Your input was a number"); 
else
   printf("Your input was not a number.\n");
```

When I test this program and I enter a number, C returns the else statement (Your input was not a number.). So regardless of if I enter a number or a letter, the program returns the else statement.

Why is this so?

Comment: isdigit works on char type, not int. Read with %c

Comment: The C library function void isdigit(int c) checks if the passed character is a decimal digit character.

Comment: @stark Detail: `isdigit(int)` accepts a `int` argument and works in the range `[0...UCHAR_MAX]` and `EOF`.  Values read via `"%c"` are UB if passed to `isdigit()` and are negative (and not `EOF`).

Answer (score 2):

`isdigit()` checks if a *single character* that was passed to it by converting the char value an `unsigned char`.
So, you can't directly pass any int value and expect it to work.

Man `isdigit()` says:

```
   isdigit()
          checks for a digit (0 through 9).
```

To check single digit, you can modify:

```
char inChar;
printf("enter input:");
scanf(" %c", &inChar);

if (isdigit((unsigned char)inChar)) {
   printf("Your input was a number"); 
}
else {
printf("Your input was not a number.\n");
}
```

If you have an array (a string containing a number) then you can use a loop.

Comment: You can pass an int just fine, `isdigit` actually expects an `int` type. The problem is that a digit read with `%d` gives the numerical value, not the ASCII value.

Comment: As the prototype has it, it's valid to pass an int directly. But the isdigit() requires the value was representable in an unsigned char. So, as a generalized solution converting it to unsigned char required. (Otherwise, have to ensure the value passed meets that requirement). So, yes you are right (but with caveats).

Comment: Detail: "the `isdigit()` requires the value was representable in an `unsigned char`" or `EOF`.

Answer (score 2):

The function's purpose is to classify characters (like `'3'`). Running it on something that's read using `%d` doesn't make sense.

You should read a single `char` using `%c`. Remember to check that reading succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

The C library function void `isdigit(int c)` checks if the passed character is a decimal digit character.

If you badly wanna try it with an `int` you can init in this way

```
int inChar = '2';
```

The following code gave expected results.

```
int main()
{
    char inChar;
    printf("enter input:");
    scanf(" %c", &inChar);
    if (isdigit(inChar))
        printf("Your input was a number. \n");
    else
        printf("Your input was not a number.\n");
    return 0;   
}
```

Output:

```
vinay-1> ./a.out
enter input:1
Your input was a number
```

Comment: Now it's OK, you can delete all comments, I'll delete this one too in a few minutes.